# How to run a tabular function multiple times (with different arguments each time)

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, ssms, tabular

I have a tabular function where I'd like to pull the following:

```
select LastName, 
       FirstName, 
       Location, 
       Sales
from fnGetStuff (DateID)
```

and I'd like to run it multiple times for a bunch of DateIDs, say (2001, 2004, 2005, 2011)

Is there a way to get the tabular function to run multiple times with each of the DateIDs as an argument?

Researching it I see that CROSS APPLY may be an answer but not sure.

Comment: By database you mean Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, CROSS APPLY is what you want. Select the DateIds from some table / subquery and then cross apply agaist your function

Answer (score 0):

You can have a recursive `CTE` to get the required number of years and use that result to do cross apply to get all data points for all the years.

```
;with cte(DateID, N)
as
(
  select 2011 as DateID, 1
  union all
  select DateID+1 , N+1
  from CTE
  WHERE N < =2
)
select * from cte
CROSS APPLY
select LastName, 
       FirstName, 
       Location, 
       Sales
from fnGetStuff (cte.DateID)
```

Comment: So SQL Server 2012 doesn't seem to like the last select statement - before the LastName... Incorrect syntax...

Comment: Putting parentheses around the bit after CROSS APPLY seemed to work.  What would I have to do if I wanted not 2012, 2013, 2014 but instead wanted random years (1995, 2001, 2002, 2013) say?

Comment: @Ken, IF you want random years, change cte to ;with cte as ( select 1995 as DateID UNION select 2001 as DateID)